# Scala: Use function and inner object with the same name

Tags: scala

For the convenience of my users, I'd like to design an interface like the following:

```
class MyApplication {
  def help = "usage..."

  object help {
    def topics : List[String] = List( ... )
  }
}
```

But of course, the collision of the function and the object called `help` make this impossible.

Is there any way to do this in Scala? eg, Have one behaviour if the user calls `help` with nothing following, and another behaviour if they call `help.topics`?

(If not, what is the idiomatic *Scala* way to do something similar?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have a class where `.help` returns a `String` while `.help.topics` returns a `List[String]`. But here is an option for your application that uses a helper class. This would be more applicable if you have a range of classes each with their own help information.

```
abstract class Help {
  val usage: String
  val topics: List[String]

  def apply() = usage
  override def toString = usage
}

class MyApplication {
  object help extends Help {
    val usage = "usage"
    val topics = List("Topic1", "Topic2")
  }
}

val a = new MyApplication

println(a.help)
println(a.help())
println(a.help.topics)
```

Comment: Thanks! You've also answered another question that's been simmering in the back of my brain... I tend to avoid parens in 0-parameter functions because I find less noise makes the code easier to read. (I know many people develop conventions about when to use them, and what it means.) But I've been wondering if there's any case where they are necessary - and you've found it! Thanks again!

Comment: @LeoOrientis The general rule is to use `()` when calling a method that changes state but omit them for pure functional accessors. E.g. `x.close()` but `x.isOpen`. So this use of `help()` is not really in line with this rule, and using `x.help.usage` would be a better pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible to achieve if `def help` is transformed into `apply` inside `object help`:

```
class MyApplication {

  object help {

    def topics : List[String] = List("a", "b")

    def apply(): String = "usage..."
  }
}
```

Now, it compiles and the following calls are possible:

```
val myApp = new MyApplication()

myApp.help()
myApp.help.topics
```

However, there are still the parentheses in `.help()` to use, otherwise `myApp.help` remains a function reference.

Comment: Fascinating! This was more or less my approach, but it didn't work because I'd left the parens off of `def apply()`. It compiles, but the compiler then refuses to accept the symbol `help()`.